# How to find multiple of a number in c++

Tags: c++, math

for example I have an variable of int data type...Now i want to find out all possible multiple pair of that number.   Take integer as 12 So ans should be (3,4) (6,2) (1,12) ...using c++ only.

Comment: This is not a site where you get people to do your homework for you. If you want help with your homework then show us the code you've written so far, and you will get help with it.

Comment: you are looking for divisors. As you are still looking for an algorithm this question is about maths, not about c++

Comment: actually i got stuck at end of a problem at hackerrank....i almost solved the problem only i needed to print the multiples of an integer(obtained from the code i have written)..that's where i stuck...BTW don't bother someone else answered this and i got it...thanks for your humble polite and kind words..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start iterating from 2 to square root of number in question. operator % allows check if value is actually a divider. Result of division is the second of the pair, if result of % is zero. If value is  greater than  the second from previous pair, you can stop.